# RAID Configuraiton for Home Server

Tags: server, raid, home-directory

I want to Install & Configure Ubuntu Server as my Home Server.

These are my requirements.

1. Configuration for RAID (2 desktop HDD each with 1TB)
   Which RAID configuration is best suited for retaining data even if an HDD fails?
2. Main purpose of above step is for configuration of File Server accessible by all devices (Between PC, Mobiles, TV).
3. Backup Server for my Desktop and Mobiles.

Awaiting your valuable suggestions and inputs

Regards,

Ananda

Answer (score 1):

With two hard disks you have only two options for software RAID, which is RAID0 and RAID1.

RAID0 is pretty uncommon and only for setups where speed is important. 
With RAID0 one will lose all data if one disk breaks.

RAID1 is mirroring, and perfect for your setup.
If one disk breaks you would have a mirrored copy on the other disk.

See also :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

Comment: If, I configure server with RAID 1 now and in future, I want to configure RAID 5 or 6 adding additional HDD. Is this possible?

Comment: Raid5 is quite popular, and can be done with three disks (or more) if I'm not mistaken. You cannot go from RAID1 to RAID5 directly, you would have to back up and start from scratch with a new RAID array.